# Why does Haskell presume the returned monad type is the same type that is passed as an argument?

Tags: function, haskell, types, monads

Why does this code compile?

```
--sequence_mine :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence_mine [] = return []
sequence_mine (elt:l) = do
  e <- elt
  sl <- sequence l
  return (e:sl)
```

Note I intentionally commented out the type declaration here. But the code still compiles and seems to work as expected, even without the type declaration - and this is what surprises me.

To my understanding, ambiguity should arise on this line:

```
return (e:sl)
```

The reason is that Haskell shouldn't know which type of monad we are returning. Why does it have to be the same type that we are accepting?

To clarify more. To my understanding, if I don't explicitely put the type declaration analogous to the one I commented out, Haskell should deduce this function has a typing like this:

```
sequence_mine :: (Monad m1, Monad m2) => [m1 a] -> m2 [a]
```

Unless I explicitely unify `m1` and `m2` by calling them both `m`, there is no reason for Haskell to believe they both refer to the same type! I would suppose.

Yet that is not the case. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let's look at what the `do` block desugars to:

```
sequence_mine (elt:l) = elt >>= \e -> (sequence l) >>= \sl -> return (e:sl)
```

Recall that the "bind" operator `>>=` has the type signature `(Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. Note that the monad `m` here, although arbitrary, must be the same for both of the arguments and the result type.

So if `elt` has type `m a`, it's easy to see that the `return (e:sl)` - which is the output type of the whole expression - must have type `m [a]`, for the same monad `m`.

To put it another way, each `do` block only works in the context of a fixed monad.